# JQuery mobile app - form security issues

Tags: jquery, security, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building my first app using jquery mobile, which involves users entering info into a form, which is then stored in an sqlite database. I plan on deploying it with phonegap.

What measures should I be taking to make sure malicious code isn't entered into the form?

I can't use server-side scripting with phonegap if I understand correctly.

I'm aware this is possibly one of the pitfalls of coding an app this way...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with the environment you need, but one thing is certain; If you don't have access to the server-side part of the equation, you can sanitize and validate your data client-side, and that is always bypassable...I would however assume that phonegap will somehow handle at least basic security measures at their side, might be worth contacting their support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are simply storing this data in a SQLite DB and doing nothing else with it, really the only thing you have to sanitize the data for would be SQL injection attacks; here's a [quick example that Google brings up](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/2384).

Comment: Thanks - I did a bit of googling from that and found this article: http://bit.ly/fqmvEC - as long as you use the `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO table (id) values (?)', [id]);` form, that provides some protection.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap runs your code in its own environment which doesn't have any tools to modify or break your JavaScript code. And although I feen weird saying that - you can sanitize your inputs with javascript as long as it's in the same function that sends them (so that no error of program flow design can cause it to be skipped)

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX for server side validation, just send all the fields over on submission, if error display what needs to be fixed, else submit